# ANTLR4 - How do I get the token TYPE as the token text in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Say I have a grammar that has tokens like this:

```
AND        : 'AND' | 'and' | '&&' | '&';
OR         : 'OR' | 'or' | '||' | '|' ;
NOT        : 'NOT' | 'not' | '~' | '!';
```

When I visualize the ParseTree using TreeViewer or print the tree using tree.toStringTree(), each node's text is the same as what was matched.

So if I parse "A and B or C", the two binary operators will be "and" / "or".
If I parse "A && B || C", they'll be "&&" / "||".

What I would LIKE is for them to always be "AND" / "OR / "NOT", regardless of what literal symbol was matched. Is this possible?

Comment: `toStringTree` is just a debugging feature, you can do what you want within your own code. I don't really understand what your problem is. [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) maybe?

Comment: To put it another way, when traversing the ParseTree and printing the text associated with a node, it is the original literal symbol ("&&") rather than the token type ("AND").

Answer (score 10):

This is what the vocabulary is for. Use `yourLexer.getVocabulary()` or `yourParser.getVocabulary()` and then `vocabulary.getSymbolicName(tokenType)` for the text representation of the token type. If that returns an empty string try as second step `vocabulary.getLiteralName(tokenType)`, which returns the text used to define the token.