# Map token type integer to string in ANTLR4

Tags: java, token, antlr4

I am new to ANTLR4. I am trying process a toy language called Mo and print the token text and its type.

The following is my Mo.java file:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import static org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams.fromFileName;

public class Mo {

  public static void main (String [] args) {

    CharStream cs = null;

    try {
        cs = fromFileName(args[0]);  //load the file

    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("No input file: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
    } 


        MoLexer lexer = new MoLexer(cs);  //instantiate a lexer
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer); //scan stream for tokens
        MoParser parser = new MoParser(tokens);  //parse the tokens

        ParseTree tree = parser.molang(); // parse the content and get the tree

        MoWalker listener = new MoWalker();


        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        walker.walk(listener,tree);
  }
}
```

and this is my MoWalker.java file:

```
public class MoWalker extends MoBaseListener {

public void enterMicrolang(MoParser.MolangContext ctx ) {

    for (int i = 0; i<ctx.children.size()-1; i++){

        Token representedToken = ((TerminalNodeImpl) ctx.getChild(i)).getSymbol();
        System.out.print("Token: "+representedToken.getText());
        int typee = representedToken.getType();
        System.out.println(" --- "+typee);
    }
}

public void exitMicrolang(MicroParser.MicrolangContext ctx ) {
        System.out.println( "Exiting R" );
  }
}
```

**My problem**: 
Instead of printing the type of token as an integer, I want to print its name. (i.e. if type is INTLITERAL(==4) instead of printing 4 I want to print INTLITERAL)
I so this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106771/antlr4-how-do-i-get-the-token-type-as-the-token-text-in-antlr), but it uses Vocabulary class.

Is there any other way, like something along the lines of `getSymbolType(int type) ?`

Comment: "I so this post, but it uses Vocabulary class." Why is that a problem?

Comment: According to this, I have to build it manually. Wouldn't it be easier to use the mapping itself? 
https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/VocabularyImpl.html#getSymbolicName-int-

Comment: And by "directly" you mean "by calling a single method directly on the lexer without calling another method, such as `getVocabulary`, first"? Why? What's the reason for that requirement?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "build it manually" or "use the mapping itself". As far as I can tell, the `getSymbolicName` method solves your problem exactly and easily.

Comment: I think my problem is I don't know how to pass the vocabulary to my MicroWalker class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Vocabularyy.getSymbolicName` takes a token type as an integer and returns the name of the associated lexer rule as a string. So in other words, it gives you exactly what you want.

To get at the vocabulary for your lexer, you can call `getVocabulary` on your lexer object or use the static variable `VOCABULARY` on your lexer class. So:

```
int typee = representedToken.getType();
String typeName = MoLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(typee);
System.out.println(" --- " + typeName);
```

Comment: I see. Now I understand it.
+1 for the clear explanation